# Why do people get headaches after oversleeping?

Tags: sleep, pain

I've tried a web search, but the results are mostly non-scientific advice on good sleep etc. [One link](https://www.healthline.com/health/headache-from-oversleeping#primary-causes) provides some explanation, but I have not noticed them providing links to that referenced research:

> Getting too much sleep is actually a common headache trigger.
>
> Multiple explanations exist for why exactly this happens, but
> scientists have dug into some research on this connection. Serotonin
> disruption
>
> Some research suggests that oversleeping has effects on
> neurotransmitters in your brain — particularly on one (rather famous)
> neurotransmitter called serotonin. ....

What is current status of scientific research for such phenomena? Please provide links to studies etc.

Comment: I don’t think the place for this question is Biology, but it may well be appropriate on SE Medical Sciences.

Comment: Maybe I better rephrase, but I am interested in biological underlying mechanism of pain from oversleep, AFAIK it is not considered a decease, so I posted here.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me, so I suspect one also needs to ask what genetics are involved too. [It seems](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3997296/) circadian rhythm disruptions are suspected as the cause in such cases.

Comment: More recent review https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6381824/

Comment: It may not be a disease, but headache is a medical condition. that I would consult a medic rather than a biologist about if it affected me. SE Medical Science considers the science underlying medical conditions.

Comment: Is there data to suggest that this is a common/universal phenomenon?

Comment: Headache (by any cause) is still a frustratingly not understood phenomenon from a neuroscience perspective.

Comment: Is it even possible to get too much sleep?  As opposed to the more common use of "oversleeping" as not getting up in time for work, school, or whatever - in which case your body probably needed the sleep.

Comment: @jamesqf, internet finds entries from search for headache from oversleeping - that is sleeping too much (as they say).